# Como entrar a un archivo que esta 3 carpetas antes en php?

Tags: php

Tengo un archivo llamado **config.php**
que esta en:

```
localhost/
    Proyecto/
      -> config.php
```

y estoy en un archivo llamado **delete.php** en:

```
localhost/
    Proyecto/
         views/
            delete/
                -> delete.php
       -> config.php
```

Estoy haciendo que los archivos hagan un **require** al archivo **config.php** pero esta muchas carpetas antes, como le hago para que funcione sin tener que poner la ruta del navegador?

Por ejemplo asi **require '../config.php';** Nota. Este no sirve

Comment: Intenta con `__DIR__ .'/../config.php',` dime si te funciona o es `__DIR__ .'/../../config.php'`, creo que no entendí bien el que tanto quieres retroceder

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1. La solución  a corto plazo es utilizar:** `"../../../config.php"`

**2. La solución a largo plazo  y buena practica para todos tus proyectos :**

Define una constante  al inicio de tu proyecto

```html
$HOME=$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"];
define("RAIZ",$HOME);
```

Ahora todas las direcciones las tratas desde esa dirección

```html
require  RAIZ .'/micarpeta/micarpeta2/documento.php';
```

Si hay una direccion muy larga que es recurrente (la utilizas mucho) creas una constante para ello

```html
$HOME=$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"];
define("RAIZ",$HOME);
define("STRIPE",RAIZ."/carpeta1/carpeta2/carpeta3/stripe/");
```

la utilizas de la siguiente manera

```html
 require  STRIPE .'/documento.php';
```

Recuerda que estas constantes las defines una vez y estarán disponibles en toda tu aplicación. crear un documento **constantes.php**

así te olvidas de estar escribiendo

```
"../../.././../../carpeta/documento.php"
```